# How to add scrollbar to a div for increasing dynamic table?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm adding new TRs to one table dynamically from an link click and as the table gets bigger I need to create a scrollbar inside the div how can I accomplish that?

```
$( "#aAdd").click(function() {    
   var tableHtml = "<tr><td><input type='text' /></td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr>";
   $("#tbInfo").append(tableHtml);
});
```

Comment: Wrap the table inside a div and set a desired `max-height:XXXpx` and `overflow: auto` to the div.

Answer (score 2):

Use a div-container for your table

### HTML

```
<div class="myScrollTable">

   <table></table>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.myScrollTable{
   max-height:400px; /*example*/
   overflow: auto; /* auto , scroll .. */
}
```

**Overflow**

> The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an
>   element's box.

**Max-height**

> The max-height property is used to set the maximum height of an element. This prevents the  value of the height property from becoming larger than max-height.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table inside a div and set a desired `max-height:XXXpx` and `overflow: auto` to the div.

```js
$("#aAdd").click(function() {
  $("#tbInfo").append("<tr><td><input type='text' /></td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
});
```

```css
.tableContainer {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button "Add Rows" to add more rows and you will see the scrollbard when the height goes beyond 200px</p>
<div class="tableContainer">
  <table id="tbInfo">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="aAdd">Add Rows</button>
```